# Instance RAM monitoring

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles, azure-virtual-machine

Why is there no metric for RAM in the the monitoring section for instances in the Management Portal?

[image: Azure Web Role Monitoring]

Is there a better way to monitor such data other than using the portal?

Comment: Commercial products exist.. check CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - a successor to AzureWatch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both commercial or community tools for monitoring. If You are looking for monitoring as a service, try DataDog. If You have no problem with administration, try Zabbix or Icinga - both are open source, but You need VM for them. Of cours this VM can be inside Your Azure Virtual Network. If You ok with DataDog, there is an option in new Azure portal to install its agent on VM at the provisioning stage.